# Disable Git Rename Detection

Tags: git, merge, rename

1. I have a file, `foo.txt`
2. Create and checkout branch 'branch_A'
3. `git mv foo.txt bar.txt` followed by `git add -A` then `git commit -m "renamed foo.txt"`
4. Checkout master, `git checkout master`
5. remove foo.txt and commit.
6. Now merge branch_A, `git merge branch_A`

And with this, I get an merge conflict (rename/delete).

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): Rename foo.txt->bar.txt in branch_A and deleted in HEAD
```

This makes sense and is what I'd expect.  However, I'd like to know if there is a way for git merge to *not* detect renames, but instead treat them as added/deleted.  In this case, I'd expect git to detect that foo.txt was deleted and simply add bar.txt.  No conflict.

I've tried using -X rename-threshold, but it has not worked for me.  I've tried thresholds 0 and 120 (a number above 100).  What am I missing?

Thanks!

P.S.  I'm also getting `error: refusing to lose untracked file at...` errors.  What does this mean?

Comment: `error: refusing to lose untracked file at...` could be the result of merging `bar.txt`, which was tracked in `branch_A` but untracked in `master`, assuming that it exists in your working directory

Comment: With git 2.8 (March 2016), you will have the option of doing a `git merge --no-renames`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35672618/6309)

Comment: With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), you have the option of `git config merge.renames false`. See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672618/6309).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
git merge -s resolve branch_A
```

This will enable *resolve* merge strategy, which does not try to detect renames:

> `resolve`
>
> This can only resolve two heads (i.e. the current branch and another branch you pulled from) using a 3-way merge algorithm. It tries to carefully detect criss-cross merge ambiguities. It does not handle renames.

Also, have you tried looking at similar questions here:

[git rename/delete confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100032/git-rename-delete-confusion)

[git divergent renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679901/git-divergent-renaming)

Comment: This really needs more explanation

Comment: Basically I had `file.txt` that I had modified and move to the `foo` subdirectory, and then backtracked in history and used the same `file.txt` as a starting point to modify it and move it to a `bar` directory. Then I tried to merge the two branches, wanting to wind up with separate `foo` and `bar` versions of the file with a history going back to the same source. Using `-s resolve` as @manojlds indicated worked beautifully, but as Liam mentioned, it really does need more explanation. But thanks so much manojlds for the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Update Sept. 2021:

The 2016 option mentioned below is now obsolete, and replaced by the new [merge strategy ORT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950077/6309) ("Ostensibly Recursive's Twin"), which does a much better job handling rename detection.

> The primary difference noticable here is that the updating of the working tree and index is not done simultaneously with the merge algorithm, but is a separate post-processing step.
>
> The new API is designed so that one can do repeated merges (e.g. during a rebase or cherry-pick) and only update the index and working tree one time at the end instead of updating it with every intermediate result.
>
> Also, one can perform a merge between two branches, neither of which match the index or the working tree, without clobbering the index or working tree.
>
> The "ort" backend does the complete merge inmemory, and only updates the index and working copy as a post-processing step.

Starting with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), this will be the default.
In the meantime:

```
git merge -s ort MyBranch-to-merge
          ^^^^^^
```

---

2016:

With git 2.8 (March 2016), you will have another option (as an option to the recursive merge strategy)

```
git merge -Srecursive -Xno-renames
```

See [commit 44c74ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44c74ecade186d7c7047642840d581709db3ba23), [commit 2307211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2307211349e6fe83e3574c2e1a03bb34c24ed1b9), [commit 63651e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63651e1a13f29abcffb1d197f3388924318d59d3) (24 Feb 2016), [commit 2307211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2307211349e6fe83e3574c2e1a03bb34c24ed1b9), [commit 63651e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63651e1a13f29abcffb1d197f3388924318d59d3) (24 Feb 2016), [commit 87892f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87892f605be16037bc910ca2cf9fa21bb9467f5e), [commit 83837ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83837ec0b43bfd832ea00cd96e8b47c90991c473) (21 Feb 2016), and [commit 1b47ad1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b47ad160b55f50a7a98c180e18d80f0f8f17a67), [commit d2b11ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2b11eca7eccc4dfc22a8fc1182d9341458dd9cb) (17 Feb 2016) by [Felipe Gonçalves Assis (`asiz`)](https://github.com/asiz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4ce064d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ce064dd813279109a4003dee8c8b63077ab473d), 26 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### `merge-recursive`: option to disable renames
>
> The recursive strategy turns on rename detection by default.
> **Add a strategy option to disable rename detection even for exact renames**.

The [man `git-merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d2b11eca7eccc4dfc22a8fc1182d9341458dd9cb/Documentation/merge-strategies.txt#L84-L86) will include:

> ```
> no-renames
> ```
>
> Turn off rename detection.
> See [`git diff --no-renames`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

(Note, as seen in [commit 1b47ad1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b47ad160b55f50a7a98c180e18d80f0f8f17a67), the `find-renames` merge strategy, following `git diff` interface, makes the option `rename-threshold` redundant starting with git 2.8)

---

You have an additional setting with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018): with the `merge.renames` configuration set to false, the recursive merge strategy can be told not to spend cycles trying to find renamed paths and merge them accordingly.

See [commit 6f10a09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f10a09e0a1a7c3c3a6ee8e67390a4839dbe6a1b), [commit 85b4603](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85b460305ce7ed399c83499851f46c4f870ce280), [commit a7152e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7152e9d226652e6ceaa64f099fc628aa2a909bd) (02 May 2018) by [Ben Peart (`benpeart`)](https://github.com/benpeart).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6e2ba77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e2ba77bda8a23f911ac7e6dd8a313f4f03afb5e), 30 May 2018)</sup>

> `merge`: add `merge.renames` config setting
>
> Add the ability to control rename detection for merge via a config setting.
> This setting behaves the **same and defaults to the value of `diff.renames` but only applies to merge**.

Comment: was this removed in 2.9? The git maintainers ppa of stable releases does not have this flag AFAICT.

Comment: @ThorSummoner I agree. It is actually an option to a merge strategy. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @VonC: may I offer 2 tiny edits: add hyphen in git-merge; drop double-hyphen before no-renames. Should say: "The man git-merge will include: no-renames"

Comment: @chrisinmtown Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.