# Why does git merge generate conflicts across different files?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I'm trying to merge a branch with the master one. Surprisingly, git identified conflicts across different files! 
I'm used to conflicts in the same file but cannot understand the concept behind conflicts between different files.

Here is the case:

- there are 2 branches: `master` and `branch1`
- `file1.ini`:

  - in `master`: has been removed
  - in `branch1`: has been modified (compared to common ancestor with `master`)
- `master` has a new file: `folderA/file2.ini`
- `file1` was not moved to `folderA/file2.ini`

After the merge command:

- `file1.ini` has been deleted
- new 'folderA/file2.ini`contains conflict markers like:

  <<<<<<< HEAD:file1.ini

  ...

  =======

  ...

  >>>>>>>  master:folderA/file2.ini

I'm puzzled about the file mixing.

Comment: Was the commit in which `file1.ini` was deleted different from the commit in which it was added back as `folderA/file2.ini`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does dynamic rename detection, based on file similarity.  The removed `file1.ini` was more similar to the retained `folderA/file2.ini` than the deletion, so git attempted to treat this as a rename-and-edit.

(In short, it's just an algorithm misfire in this particular case.)

Comment: Thanks! I will try the following for avoiding this detection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013261/disable-git-rename-detection