# Git: pulling from the "original" branch

Tags: git

I'm still learning git and currently just using it as a single user. I find it to be a good way to test out some features and separate the dev into branches..

Would it be possible to do the following marked with red?

[image]

I want to rename the files that I have changed in the 2nd branch - the change should be both in the 1st and 2nd branch...

Comment: i don't see any "1st branch" or "2nd branch" in your graphics, so the text doesn't make sense (and I have the suspicion, that what you want can be expressed in words without graphics)

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something, or are you just talking about merging two branches?

Comment: Say I have File A with some working code on the 1st branch. I make a 2nd branch to try out some major code changes in file A. I then realized that it would have been better calling it B. If I go back to 1st branch rename A to B. Go back to 2nd branch and do a merge with 1st branch I'll get 2 files: File A (old name, but new major changed code - still not working code) and File B (new name, but old code)...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is simply called `merging` in git speak.

Git does a quite good job for tracking file-renames, so in most cases it will correctly figure out that you have changed the content in `fileA` in one branch and renamed `fileA` to `fileB` in another branch. Doing a *merge* should then rename the file and incorporate the rename.

However, for this to work, the renamed file must be either *sufficiently* similar (so git has a chance to note that this is meant to be the same file), or you must trigger a rename explicitely via `git mv`

See also

- [git merge with renamed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701790/git-merge-with-renamed-files)
- [Disable Git Rename Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013261/disable-git-rename-detection/35672618#35672618)

Comment: doens't `git mv` not just move the file?

Comment: what's the difference between *move* and *rename*?