# Merging branches with similar branch signatures

Tags: git, git-merge

I want to merge master branch into my development branch. While in my development branch, I execute the following:

''' git pull origin master'''

When I do this, the merge finishes, however, I notice very odd behavior. It seems that a folder in master is so similar to my branch, it treats them as the same folder.

I have tried creating a new branch from master and pull in the changes from development into master, but it does the same thing. It treats the folders as if they are the same.

For example, I have the following:

Master
src->folder1

Development
src->folder2

After the merge, I get

Developement
src->folder1

instead of

Developement
src->folder1
src->folder2

EDIT: The file names are mostly identical, however, the contents of the files are not identical at all. Development is done in C++, so the namespaces make it clear who is what.

EDIT: Hey gang, I tried the recommendations, however, git was still doing the renaming. Instead, I just branched from master and brought in the folders I needed. Now when I merge master, it is always up-to-date. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: What are the contents of the folders? If the folders contain identical files, it probably thinks you intended to rename the folder, because obviously no one would ever want to have identical files in two different folders. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Git Rename Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013261/disable-git-rename-detection)

Comment: What do you mean by "folders are similar"? Do you mean the files in the folders are similar?

Comment: They are similar in that 90% of the file names are the same. Having said that, the contents of the file are much different.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the feature that is being triggered here is "rename detection". Because git only records snapshots, not the intent of changes, file moves, copies, and renames are detected by comparing the contents of files. It seems that in your case, git is detecting the contents as being sufficiently similar that it probably represented a rename on one branch or the other.

You can disable this behaviour:

- In a single `git pull` invocation by adding `-X no-renames` which sets [the `no-renames` strategy option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-no-renames)
- By default for a checkout or installation by setting [the `mergerenames` config option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-mergerenames) to `false`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is due to *directory rename detection*. You can turn it off with

```
git -c merge.directoryRenames=false pull origin master
```

This leaves normal rename detection operative.