# Why are my changes being moved to another file on Git Merge?

Tags: git

In a new branch I've created a new file (File A) and have written some code on it.

Merging to the development branch I get a merge conflict in an old file, File B. Running `git diff` against it I see that File B is overwritten by the same changes I have done on File A.

Would anyone know why this is and how I could fix it?

Note that I have not worked on File B on this new branch and that File A seems to be deleted by the merge.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  [`-Xno-renames` to your git merge command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672618/6309), to see if this is a case where Git believes `FileB` is a renaming of `FileA` (because of a similar content)

```
git merge -Xno-renames development
```

Or (Git 2.18+, Q2 2018):

```
git -c merge.renames=false development
```