# Git, when renaming on both branches, not detected as rename

Tags: git, rename

Many questions where asked about Git not detecting rename after content change.
I have a different problem:
On common ancestor there is file f_rename.txt.
On one branch (diverge) I rename(only, not content change) to f_rename_1.txt
On other branch rename only to f_rename_2.txt

When merging the two branches, I get conflicts:

[image]

I can't understand this behaviour, even if I assume that Git doesn't detect the rename operation and f_rename_1 is assumed to be a new file, then why it marked as conflict ? conflict with what ?

Looking at stage files, it is clear that files where not modified(same SHA1):
[image]

I was expecting to rename/rename as in [Git conflict (rename/rename)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732639/git-conflict-rename-rename)

I'm not asking how to resolve the conflict !, but why Git behaves like this.
I'm using Git '2.13.3.windows.1'

Thanks
Boaz

Comment: If it wouldn't detect the rename, than it would not trigger a conflict. But since git knows that two renames happened, which are obviously in conflict with each other it generates a conflict. Why do you think the two renames are not in conflict? They tackle the same file in two impossible to combine ways. That's a conflict.

Comment: @Nils_M I understood my mistake, thanks to torek answer, I just still can't  understand in case of large number of conflicts how can one analyzes and understand that this is rename/rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you included in your question has `git status` output.

The `CONFLICT (rename/rename):` that you are expecting is printed by the `git merge` command.

The *trace* that this leaves behind in the index, which you are now seeing, is that the index has one stage-1 entry for the original name (with no stage-2 or stage-3 entry), one stage-2 entry for one of the new names (with no stage-1 or stage-3 entry), and one stage-3 entry for the other new name (with no stage-1 or stage-2 entry).  The `git status` command prints that output for that kind of trace.

Look at the accepted answer to your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732639/git-conflict-rename-rename), which shows the same `git status` output.  The `both deleted` line simply comes later, because the output is sorted by file names, and `will-be-deleted` starts with `w` which comes later.

Comment: So @torek,  in case of more than few conflicts, the developer should analyzes and detects these triple of conflicts and understand that it is rename/rename ? Is there a way to ease this analysis ?

Comment: If you save the `CONFLICT ...` error-message output from the `git merge` command, you'll have the necessary information. It seems to me that Git really *should* write this to the index, making it retrievable for automation and for better `git status` output, since there are different kinds of what I call "high level" merge conflicts that become hard to distinguish without that data. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44360581/1256452)